# How do I get into the Gallimimus enclosure?

Tags: lego-jurassic-world

This is the enclosure directly in front of you as you enter the Jurassic Park area - when the road forks left and right to start the loop, the enclosure is between the forks.  The Prima guide has this description of how to access it:

> This area is a bit tougher to get into than some of the others. There is a tunnel that goes under the road leading back to the main gate. Use a character with the ability to repair and fix the controls and open the gate to the tunnel. Then move through the tunnel to get into the Gallimimus enclosure where the map kiosk is located.

Unfortunately, they fail to include useful details like where to find the tunnel.  How do I get to this area?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access it from the t-Rex territory, just keep going to the left once you're in, and eventually you'll find your way in.  You'll see the sign post thing for the "restoring power" stage.  Also, you can get to it from the main gate by sticking to the right.  You'll see the Dennis Nedry mini figure/character by the vending machine.